# Error when making .bat file to open programs? scripting

Tags: powershell, batch-file

****so this is how the bat file program look like and the error code i am geting ( click the drop box link/copy and paste to browser)****

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/6o4h666m0bwav69/AACTAbDe4jhyWdApEQOoAl7Na?dl=0

only program that is coming up is hitmanpro, every others get error

Comment: Please add your actual code to the question.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, paste your code and error directly into your questions in the future.

Now then, the issue comes from the incorrect quotes being used. See how the first three pairs are kinda curly and the last ones are straight? Batch can't recognize curly quotes, probably because it's some Unicode thing. Always use straight quotes in batch. It's best if you code in notepad or a similar program; some text editors make the quotes curly automatically and call them "smart quotes."

Comment: @jzjaisil - happy to help. Since my answer worked for you, please click the check next to my answer to mark it as Accepted.